# Upload more than 1.5MB (web.config)

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, file-upload

how i can upload more than 1.5MB?

i modified my web.config file, but it's not working properly, it's just uploading maximum 1.5MB.

you can find my code below:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
 <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="67108864" targetFramework="4.5"/>

 <system.webServer>
   <security>
         <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
         </requestFiltering>

   </security>

 </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

for upload file:

```
    $http({ method: 'POST', url: rootURL + '/uploadfileFUNC', }).success(function (data) {
        alert("File successfuly uploded.");
    })
```

'uploadfileFUNC' is my function in asp.net

Error:

```
POST http://localhost:8090/uploadfileFUNC 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

if i have to change any thing inside mentioned code or some were else please let me know.

thanks

Comment: "It's not working"... the most unhelpful statement possible. What is not working, what is it doing that it shouldn't, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: I thinks he means, he can upload maximum 1.5MB. He cant upload the file with more than this size.

Comment: @freefaller And this is a part of a Webconfig file statement.
He want to upload the file with more than 1.5MB. But he can't
Maybe he must check the directive or the upload code.

Comment: Do you have try to use any upload control and make a test ? I have use of them, upload many files, more than 1.5Mg and never have any issues, nether need to modify the web.config.

Comment: Please introduce Some of upload control.

Comment: google it "asp.net upload control"

Comment: The error here is not the size, but you have probably break the asp.net page. Direct use an asp.net upload control, and move on.